# Port already Using Error in Android

Tags: android, arduino, port, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I have an android application which is running on Huawei S7,Android 2.2. 
It is getting inputs from an arduino board.Arduino Board is connected to the tablet by USB cable.Application is using USB Protocol to connect to arduino.

The application is written for Android 4.1.And it is using a backward compatibility pack to make it runnable on 2.2.
We had to use a 2.2 device.But now we have a device with Android 4.3. And when we try to run the same app in 4.3 device it gives an error saying 
4567 port already in use.
4567 port is the port used by arduino application to connect with the Android Device(Tablet Application).

How can i find the application which is using the 4567 port?

Is there any way i can free up that port?

My 4.3 device is not rooted. Will rooting do any good in this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install a terminal emulator app from the Play Store and then run `lsof` and look for entries with `socket:[4567]` That should give you what is using the port. Without root you may not be able to stop the process. If you do have root you surely can.

Comment: I used the app and ran the command this is the output i got 
I didn't find the port 4567 here. Is there anyway i can expand this search or something?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8JZMxx6Km7ocXlwNVBma1VtSzQ/edit?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8JZMxx6Km7oWmF3cU01SXU2cjg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: try this command `lsof | grep socket:[4567]` That should give you the PID of the process using that port. You can then run `kill -9 <pid>` where <pid> is the PID of the process as shown by `lsof` . If it asks for root then maybe its a system process and you might need to root your device

Comment: This is the output i get when i run it 

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8JZMxx6Km7oZFpqRGJkcUV0cDQ/edit?usp=sharing

Have i run the code correctly?

Comment: Sorry for wasting your time, my mistake. I think grep is taking ":" as a regex pattern. So please run `lsof | grep socket` instead and then manually find the PID corresponding to `socket:[4567]`.

Comment: I ran the above command and this is the output i got. 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8JZMxx6Km7oRW1WQ1c5TjdBdXc/edit?usp=sharing
How do i find the PID manually? 
Sorry i'm not much familiar with the linux environment.

Comment: Here is a link that might solve your problem [link](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/24084/list-of-open-ports-on-android)

Comment: This is the command it's suggesting to run. But I am not sure about which part is the command and which part is the output.

shell@android:/ $ cat /proc/net/tcp
sl local_address rem_address st tx_queue rx_queue tr tm->when retrnsmt uid timeout inode
0: 0100007F:1C23 00000000:0000 0A 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000 1001 0 2111 1 e22cc000 300 0 0 2 -1

Can you please clarify which part of this text i should run on terminal emulator?

Comment: the command is just `cat /proc/net/tcp` rest of the text is the output of this command.